# Android- taking a picture for temporary use with the camera intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I am taking a picture with the built-in camera intent, and my app just needs the image to create one bitmap. Is it possible to avoid the image saving to the gallery without creating my own custom camera? Here is my current code to take the picture.

```
public void open() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
static Bitmap bp;

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(currentPosition);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop, but you can delete it, try this code:

```
 private void DeletePicTaken(){
            final String[] imageColumns = { BaseColumns._ID, MediaColumns.DATA };
            final String imageOrderBy = BaseColumns._ID + " DESC";
            Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);
            if(imageCursor.moveToFirst()){
                //int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
                String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA));
                //imageCursor.close();
                File file = new File(fullPath);
                file.delete();
            }


        } 

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(currentPosition);
    DeletePicTaken();
    }
```

Comment: I found the reason of the crash (I was missing the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest), however the image in the gallery persists

Comment: For anyone using this solution, make sure you have both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in your manifest. It was also necessary to update my gallery or else I would have a blank image in the place of the deleted one; this code accomplishes that: sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(latestSavedImage))); LastSavedImage is your deleted file.